# What is causing my Python script to throw a KeyError when accessing the subject line of Gmail messages?

Tags: python, gmail

I am attempting to automatically download attachments from a work gmail account into an s3 bucket. As part of my research, I am just attempting to verify that I can access the messages in the inbox. I have developed some code that looks like it should work, but it keeps coming back with an error. I just need someone to tell me where I might be going wrong here.

```
# Import the necessary modules
import googleapiclient.discovery
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def get_credentials():
    if os.path.exists('/home/matillion/gmail_token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/home/matillion/gmail_token.json', SCOPES)
    return creds

# Create a service object
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=get_credentials())

# Get the user's inbox
inbox = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=100).execute()

# Loop through the messages in the inbox
for message in inbox['messages']:
    # Get the subject line of the message
    subject = message['subject']

    # If the subject line contains the word "Zillion", print the message
    if 'Zillion' in subject:
        print(message)
```

The error that I am getting is:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/interpreter-input-5955b24e-bd35-463a-909e-6ca5f0e592a4.tmp", line 28, in 
subject = message['subject']
KeyError: 'subject'
Script failed with status: 1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`service.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=100).execute()` only gives you a list of message IDs.

if we want the message details (including headers such as `Subject`) we have to use `service.users().messages().get()`

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def get_credentials():
    if os.path.exists('/home/matillion/gmail_token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/home/matillion/gmail_token.json', SCOPES)
    return creds

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=get_credentials())

inbox = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=100).execute()

for message in inbox['messages']:
    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
    payload = msg['payload']
    headers = payload['headers']

    for d in headers:
        if d['name'] == 'Subject':
            subject = d['value']

    if 'Zillion' in subject:
        print(msg)
```